# preparedStatement with TimeStamp compare two date

Tags: java, postgresql, oracle-sqldeveloper

i have this code

```
    preparedStatement = jdbcManager.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
    Date start; /*get from postgres column type-> Timestamp without time zone*/
    java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(start.getTime());

    log.debug("Parametro d'ingresso query: "+timestamp);
    preparedStatement.setTimestamp(1, timestamp);
```

and i have this query

```
SELECT
DATA
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE DATA > ?
```

the  column DATA is DATA_TYPE = DATE   in a Oracle db

the compare in the query not working, 
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you execute a query? what do you get?

Comment: Why did you add the `postgresql` tag if you are using Oracle?

Comment: Does 'the compare not working' mean you only get data from the second day and on but not from the first day?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the The Date start is from a table in postgres with type Timestamp without time zone.

Comment: @SirRotN not working because "if >" is always TRUE  "if <" is always false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're comparing **date** with **timestamp**. Instead of fetching time stamp, get java.sql.Date. And also in prepared statement,  use setDate instead of setTimeStamp.